# PhP associative array to get more effective

Tags: php, arrays, maintainability

I would like to ask that I am having array from the form. but I need to manage the array.

```
<div class="item form-group">
<h4>Program List</h4>
</div>
<div class="new_program">
  <div class="item form-group">  
  <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12"></label>                      
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-4 col-xs-8">
  <input  type="text" name="desciplines[0]['name']" placeholder="Program Name" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12">                          
 </div>
</div>
 <div class="item form-group">  
 <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12"></label>  
 <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
 <textarea name="desciplines[0]['program_desc']" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12"></textarea>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="item form-group">
 <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12"></label>  
 <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
 <input  type="text" name="desciplines[0]['fees']" placeholder="fees" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12">
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>  
 <div class="item form-group">  
 <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12"></label>  
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
 <i class="fa fa-plus add_descipline"></i>
 </div>
 </div>
```

jQuery is

```
$(document).on('click','.add_descipline',function(e){   
            var html = $('.new_program').wrap('<p/>').parent().html();
            $( html ).insertAfter( ".new_program" );
});
```

Even though right now, I have changed the increment index with inspect element for the temporary output for now, then I will change the jQuery.

[image]

Sorry, if you not understand. Just let me know. I will explain more sincerely.

Regards

Comment: show your php code.

Comment: You dont need to change the array, all you need to do is process it with its current state in mind

Comment: Are your html generated though `loop`?

Comment: @Dave.... I just print_r the data. I already shown the html in the code section.

Comment: last 3 input fields will be generated.
more program name, program desc and program fees.

Comment: I think i have to change the array and its index to get the appropriate array.

Comment: Please edit your question and all details like `jQuery` code you are using to generate new divs. As well as what initial HTML you have. Otherwise you will not get proper solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to process the array with its current state as Riggs says in comments.
But if you want to stick with your plan, you can do this:

```
$new_desciplines = [];
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if(in_array($key, ["desciplines", "programs_descriptions", "fees"])){
        foreach ($value as $index => $val) {
            $new_desciplines[$index][$key] = $val;
        }
    }
}
```

Then use the `$new_desciplines` variable

```
print_r($new_desciplines);
```

Comment: yes, output is now as expected. Thanks for the Ans.

Thanks to all for your support as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
?>

  <form class="form-horizontal"  enctype="multipart/form-data" action="#" method="post">
      <input  type="text" name="desciplines[0]['name']" placeholder="Name">  
  <input  type="text" name="desciplines[0]['desc']" placeholder="desc">  
  <input  type="text" name="desciplines[0]['fees']" placeholder="fees">    

  <input  type="text" name="desciplines[1]['name']" placeholder="Name">  
  <input  type="text" name="desciplines[1]['desc']" placeholder="desc">  
  <input  type="text" name="desciplines[1]['feed']" placeholder="fees">    

      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>

out put

Array
(
    [desciplines] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    ['name'] => fads
                    ['desc'] => fads
                    ['fees'] => fads
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    ['name'] => fadsf
                    ['desc'] => fdasfdas
                    ['feed'] => fdasf
                )

        )

)
```